# Clearfix not working

Tags: html, css

I want to give a top-margin value to the element p inside the #footer, but the clearfix does not work and the margin keep collapsing outside its parent element, why? code below, the #fotter and the clearfix class is at the final of the code thx.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>CSS Challenge 1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">    
  </head>
  <body>
    <div  id="wrap">
      <div id="header">
        <h1>Shakespear.net</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Writings</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sonnets</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Life Story</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About Shakespear.net</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="sidebar">
        <h2>Sonnet Index</h2>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sonnet #1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sonnet #6</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sonnet #11</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sonnet #15</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sonnet #18</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="content">
        <h1>Shakespeare's Sonnet #18</h1>
        <p>This is one of the most famous of the sonnets. It is referenced
            in the film Dead Poets Society and gave names to the band The
            Darling Buds and the book and television series The Darling Buds
            of May. Read it and weep!</p>
        <ul>
          <li>Shall I compare thee to a summer's day?</li>
          <li>Thou art more lovely and more temperate:</li>
          <li>Rough winds do shake the darling buds of May,</li>
          <li>And summer's lease hath all too short a date:</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="footer" class="clearfix">
        <p class="copyright">See the 
        <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shakespeare%27s_Sonnets">
        Shakespeare's sonnets</a> Wikipedia article for more information
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html, body, #wrap {
    height: 100%;
}
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#wrap {
    max-width: 450px;
    margin: auto;
}

/************ header ************/

#header {
    background-color: #B5B67D;
    height: 16%;
}
#header h1{
    margin: 58px 34px 0;
    float: right;
    font-size: 21px;
}

/************ nav ************/

#nav {
    background-color: #689D59;
    min-height: 4%;
    border-bottom: 2px dashed white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#nav li{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 10px;
    margin: 0 4px 0 14px;
}
#nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
}   

/************ sidebar ************/

#sidebar {
    float: right;
    background-color: #B5B67D;
    width: 23%;
  min-height: 70%;
}
#sidebar h2 {
    font-size: 8px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
#sidebar li {
    font-size: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;


}

/************ content ************/ 

#content {
    float: right;
    background-color: #506449;
    width: 77%;
    min-height: 70%;
}
#content h1{
    font-size: 19px;
    margin: 18px 0 0 10px;  
}
#content p{
    font-size: 9px;
    margin: 10px
}
#content li{
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
}

/************ footer ************/

#footer {
    background-color: #689D59;
    min-height: 10%;
    clear: both;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#footer p{
  text-align: center;
    margin-top: 351px;  
}

.clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: if it was working, then the margin will not be outside the parent element,  if you put a border on the  footer parent then the margin works, I think that is telling me that is a margin collapsing problem.

Comment: Your clearfix puts the clear _after_ the footer.  You want the clear _before_ it.  What you have now will only prevent the margin of the _next_ element collapsing.

Comment: Thx, omnichad, that was the problem! make a full answer below so I can give you the best answer thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your clearfix puts the clear after the footer. You want the clear before it. What you have now will only prevent the margin of the next element collapsing.

Place the clearfix on the last element that should obey the floats.  In your case, this will work:

```
<div id="content" class="clearfix">
```

Comment: I just changed .clearfix::after for  .clearfix::before, everything fine now.

Comment: That will work great, but most people who apply the clearfix have standardized on using ::after.  That won't hurt you, but it might confuse anyone else who tries to make changes later.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

Use padding instead of margin:

```
#footer p{
  text-align: center;
    padding-top:20px
}
```

Comment: I want to know why the clearfix is not working, in case it happens again.

Comment: CSS Property clear:both that you used for footer is working and its doing the right thing as it is clearing any floats mentioned before.

Comment: also use this for header:#header h1 {
    float: right;
    font-size: 21px;
    margin: 28px 34px 0;
}

Answer (score 0):

A clearfix approach is meant to clear an element's children.  You are trying to apply it to the `footer` element, which is not what is floated.  You can try a few things:

1. Wrap the `sidebar` and `content` sections in their own `div` and apply `clearfix` to THAT div.

https://jsfiddle.net/va9q1mw8/1/

2. Scrap the clearfixes altogether and add `<div style="clear:both"></div>` immediately after the `content` div, but before the `footer`

https://jsfiddle.net/va9q1mw8/

Comment: everything was fine, I just needed to change: "after" for "before".